# Mayer-Vietoris implies Excision

Tags: algebraic-topology

Assume $H_n$ is a covariant homotopy functor on the category of locally compact Hausdorff spaces which has the Mayer-Vietoris property: whenever $X$ is the union of two closed subspaces $A$ and $B$ there is a long exact sequence

$$\to H_n(A \cap B) \to H_n(A) \oplus H_n(B) \to H_n(X) \to H_{n-1}(A \cap B) \to$$

I want to prove an excision theorem in $H_n$.  This probably takes the form of a long exact sequence

$$\to H_n(A) \to H_n(X) \to H_n(X - A) \to H_{n-1}(A) \to$$

where $A$ is a closed subset of $X$.  But in case I made a mistake in the formulation, I'm really just looking for an explanation of one direction of the slogan "the Mayer-Vietoris sequence is equivalent to the excision theorem".  I already know how to do this in ordinary homology theory (i.e. when the relevant long exact sequences come from short exact sequences of chain complexes), but I need to understand how it works when chain complexes are unavailable.

Comment: I assume $H_n$ is a sequence of functors from the homotopy category of locally compact Hausdorff spaces to the category of abelian groups. Do you want the long exact sequence to be functorial in $X, A, B$?

Comment: Yes on all accounts.

Comment: This may or may not be helpful, but the other direction (excision implies Mayer-Vietoris) is dealt with axiomatically  in the original Eilenberg-Steenrod book.  Pleasantly, you can find a searchable .pdf of the book here: http://archive.org/details/foundationsofalg033540mbp

Comment: I have been able to find other references for "excision implies Mayer-Vietoris" (for example Hatcher does it), but the argument doesn't seem to me to be reversible.  Maybe I'm just missing something.

Comment: I guess my point was that Eilenberg-Steenrod doesn't use chain complexes whereas Hatcher does.  But I have no reason to think the E-S argument can be reversed...

Comment: Is there a typo in your proposed long exact sequence with $H_n(X−A)$ in it? It didn't ring a bell, and failed for the very first example I tried it on: $H_n$ = ordinary homology, $X$ some closed ball and $A$ its boundary.

Comment: Perhaps I should have specified the morphisms in LCH: a morphism between $X$ and $Y$ is a (basepoint preserving) continuous map between their one-point compactifications, and a homotopy of maps between $X$ and $Y$ is a morphism from $X \times [0,1]$ to $Y$.  These definitions might be a little strange if you're mostly familiar with CW complexes - for instance a point is no longer nullhomotopic.